# How to copy using presigned url at amazon s3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I want to create pre-signed URL for S3-Copy operation.
I know about pre-signed for URL S3-Put but not get how to create it for S3-Copy.

Ref:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectDotNetSDK.html

My requirement is that I want to to create a signed URL, which allows the destination service to access source service object and copy it to the destination bucket.

Thanks

Comment: Did you implemented this?? Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you want to hear, but this functionality isn't supported in the AWS SDK for Java.  You can only generate pre-signed URLs to get or put an object.

In principle you can pre-sign any operation, but it gets complicated fast.  For example, the copy object operation needs specific headers which must be signed, so the pre-signed URL and the service eventually accessing that URL would both need to agree on these headers ahead of time.